# Custom Module not working | Custom Code working fine

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom

I am trying to get my custom module working and I am not sure where I am wrong.

Here is my `app/etc/[namespace]_CustomPriceRevert.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_CustomPriceRevert>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </[Namespace]_CustomPriceRevert>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I guess that works fine as I can see the module in `Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced` and it is enabled.

Here is the content of `app/code/local/[Namespace]/CustomPriceRevert/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_CustomPriceRevert>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </[Namespace]_CustomPriceRevert>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_create> Namespace]_CustomPriceRevert_Model_Sales_Order_Create</sales_order_create>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Something wrong in here?

Here is content of my model `app/code/local/[Namespace]/CustomPriceRevert/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php`:

```
<?php

class [Namespace]_CustomPriceRevert_Model_Sales_Order_Create extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create {

    public function initFromOrderItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $orderItem, $qty = null)
    {
        if (!$orderItem->getId()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($this->getSession()->getStoreId())
            ->load($orderItem->getProductId());

        if ($product->getId()) {
            $product->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);
            $buyRequest = $orderItem->getBuyRequest();
            if (is_numeric($qty)) {
                $buyRequest->setQty($qty);
            }
            $item = $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
            if (is_string($item)) {
                return $item;
            }
// Custom-code
            if (
                !$this->getSession()->getReordered()
                && $orderItem->getOriginalPrice() != $orderItem->getPrice()
            ) {
                $item->setCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($orderItem->getPrice());
            }
// end Custom-code
            if ($additionalOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
                $item->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                    array(
                        'product' => $item->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'additional_options',
                        'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
                    )
                ));
            }

            Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item', array(
                'order_item' => $orderItem,
                'quote_item' => $item
            ));
            return $item;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The custom code seems to work because when I added it to the core file it worked fine.

I'm working on magento 1.9.2.4. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what the expected results and what's happening? all you have is code and saying it doesn't work

Comment: The custom code is commented as `// Custom-code` in the `Create.php` file. Basically it saves the custom price as magento custom price is lost on Order Edit. Also the code is working, I tried adding it to the core `Create.php` file and worked fine, it's just the module that's not working.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Check everything in app/code/local and app/code/community to ensure that nothing else is overriding the same class.  Search for `extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create`.

Comment: Check for conflict, see if your function initFromOrderItem are executed or not

Comment: Is there any quick way I can check that? Or do I have to go into each module to check that?

Comment: @BareFeet your initialization file is not in correct place. It should be in app/etc/modules

Comment: There is some community modules for this you can find in marketplace or in your core file in your function initFromOrderItem echo get_class($this); die;

Comment: The initialisation file was in the wrong directory for some reason, however, moving it to the right place did not solve the issue. The module is still not working.

Comment: Are there any community modules that save the custom price on order edit? Can you give me a link? I can't find anything. Also, I wanted to do it myself to get some practise but as you can see, failed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing something on your

> app/etc/modules/[namespace]_CustomPriceRevert.xml

Update with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_CustomPriceRevert>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                 <Mage_Core />
            </depends>
        </[Namespace]_CustomPriceRevert>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: File is correct, location should be app/etc/modules/[namespace]_CustomPriceRevert.xml

Comment: Ain't working :/ I am really not sure what is the problem now. Could it be that some other modules are extending this class somewhere else? I used MageRun to see if there are any conflicts but it didn't show anything.

Comment: Can you check your local and community code pool for this class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create may be some extension has already extended this class or not?

Answer (score 0):

**I think try this.**

> app/etc/modules/Test_CustomPriceRevert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Test_CustomPriceRevert>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Test_CustomPriceRevert>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Test/CustomPriceRevert/etc/config/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Test_CustomPriceRevert>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Test_CustomPriceRevert>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <custompricerevert>
        <class>Test_CustomPriceRevert_Helper</class>
      </custompricerevert>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <custompricerevert>
        <class>Test_CustomPriceRevert_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>custompricerevert_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </custompricerevert>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_create>Test_CustomPriceRevert_Model_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create</sales_order_create>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
    </models>
  </global>
```

> app/code/local/Test/CustomPriceRevert/Model/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Create.php

```
<?php
class Test_CustomPriceRevert_Model_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create
{

}
```

Comment: That did not work :/